# Is there a way to load an Excel file into a SQL Server table in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an Excel file, sheet name is `sheet1`. In this `sheet1`, I have a data where the first 5 rows have some information like date value and some other information.

I need to load the data from `A5:Ad` range at the same time I need fetch cell A3 value it has date value in it, I need to create one column in my table as date column and need to load that cell A3 value.

In one sheet I need to do 2 functionalities like I need to take range of values and cell value from A3 cell. Please give me some advice of yours. It would be very grateful. I googled but I didn't find anything for this. Till now I tried using openrowset option but it works for range of data if I want to fetch A3 cell value data I am failing.

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: If you can fetch a range, surely you can fetch a single cell? `A3:A3` is a range which just happens to also be a single cell

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

With SSIS you can use the Excel process inside a dataflow task - but Excel must be installed on the system where you run the ssis package.

One option is to load the hole excel file into a temporary table (with an auto-id) and query this table by using SQL statements. Or, you can add a row number via script component to the ssis data flow and split the rows you need and save them into your destination table(s).